# Solve $n$-variable equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

This is an exercise in Carlo Bourlet's textbook, LECONS D'ALGEBRE ELEMENTAIRE. Sove the equations,

$$  x_1(x_2+x_3+\cdots +x_n)+2\cdot 1 (x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n)^2=9a^2 $$
$$ x_ 2(x_1+x_3+\cdots +x_n)+3\cdot 2 (x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n)^2= 25a^2 $$
$$\cdots \cdots$$
$$x_ n(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{n-1})+(n+1)\cdot n(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n)^2= (2n+1)^2a^2 $$

I tried to wtite them as,
$$  -x_1^2+x_1(x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots +x_n)+2\cdot 1 (x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n)^2=9a^2 $$
$$-x_2^2+x_2(x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots +x_n)+3\cdot 2 (x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n)^2= 25a^2 $$
$$\cdots \cdots$$
$$-x_n^2+x_n(x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots +x_n)+(n+1)\cdot n(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n)^2= (2n+1)^2a^2 $$

Then if add them together, I get,
$$  -(x^2_1+x^2_2+x^2_3+\cdots +x^2_n)+\Big[1+\sum_{i=1}^n(i^2+i)\Big] S^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(2i+1)^2a^2 $$

I do not know how to deal with the first term now. If it can be represented as function of $S$, then it will be solved.

Comment: It cannot be expressed in terms of $S$, If it could, then your original system would be highly redundant. However, you could introduce the equation $S = \sum_i x_i$, and rewrite the other equations as $x_i(S-x_i) + (i+1)iS^2 = (2i+1)^2a^2$ and treat it as a system of $n+1$ equations in the $n+1$ unknowns of $x_1, \dots, x_n, S$. (Also, it is sufficient to assume $a = 1$, since for for other $a$, you can multiply the solutions for that case by $a$.)

Comment: I have tried to solve each equation as you said. But I thought them as $n$ equations. I will try your suggestion.